# Can't get setValue to work on a Dynamics CRM editable grid

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I was hoping to get some pointers on how to do a `setValue` in a Dynamics CRM 365 (onpremise) editable grid:

No matter what I try I cannot update the values in the grid. This code gets a reference of the attribute but setValue seems to have no effect on the grid.

```
    function updateDocsOK(ctlName, grdName, attributeName) {
    var selectedRow = null;
    var attributeColl = null;
    var twoOptionValue = 0;


    try {

        //This is the Yes/No value in the dropdown
        var ctlValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(ctlName).getValue();
        if (ctlValue) {
            twoOptionValue = 1;
        }
        //get the selected rows - use the getControl method and pass the grid name.
        selectedRow = Xrm.Page.getControl(grdName).getGrid().getRows();

        //loop through rows and get the attribute collection
        selectedRow.forEach(function (row, rowIndex) {


            var att = row.getData().getEntity().attributes.getByName(attributeName);

            //This setValue does not work on a two-option
            if (att) {
                console.log(att.getValue());
                att.setValue(twoOptionValue);
                console.log(att.getValue());
            }


            //This setValue does not work on a text field
            att = row.getData().getEntity().attributes.getByName("new_testtext");

            if (att) {
                att.setValue("hello");
            }


        });
    } catch (e) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(e.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select the option to pass execution context, and use `executionContext.getFormContext()` to get the current row in editable grid.

```
function updateDocsOK(executionContext) {
    var entityObject = executionContext.getFormContext().data.entity;
    var att = entityObject.attributes.getByName("new_testtext");
    att.setValue("hello");
 }
```

> you can’t use Xrm.Page commands on editable grids. In my example I’ll
>   want to set the probability value.
>
> On the form something like
>   `Xrm.Page.getAttribute(“closeprobability”).setValue(80)` would do the
>   trick. But this won’t work on editable grids.
>
> Instead I need to use a new method that has been released with
>   Dynamics 365 (getFormContext).
>
> getFormContext returns a reference for either the form (Xrm.Page) or
>   the editable grid (GridRow). Meaning we can now have code that will
>   work in both situations.

[Read more](https://neilparkhurst.com/2016/12/30/dynamics-365-editable-grids-javascript-example/)

Comment: Thanks, but I should have described what I was trying to do. I have a field external to the grid and when the value of that changes, I want to change data in every single row in the grid.  Unless I am misunderstanding, the above example will work when fired from within the context of the grid, but my call is external.

Comment: @DaveS got it. In that case, can you update all the child records directly using service call? So by refreshing the grid it will show latest values. You just want to populate but don’t want to save?

Comment: Thanks again. Ideally, I would like to update rows/cells but not save. But if the only way to do it is a service call, then I will pursue that route.

Comment: FYI, I solved this updating each record using the Web API. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

getEventSource can be use for Dynamics CRM 365 editable grid get or set value:

```js
var year;  
 var weekNumber;  
 var selectedRow = null;  
 var attributeColl = null;  
 function dateChange(eContext) {  
   debugger;  
   var nameAttr = eContext.getEventSource();  
   var attrParent = nameAttr.getParent();  
   var startDateField = attrParent.attributes.get("new_startdate");  
   var date = startDateField.getValue();  
   //Get week number  
   var currentWeekNumber = parseFloat(date.getWeek());  
   //Get full year  
   const dt = new Date(date);  
   var currentyear = parseFloat(dt.getFullYear());  
   //set week value  
   var new_weeknumbercstField = attrParent.attributes.get("new_weeknumbercst");  
   new_weeknumbercstField.setValue(currentWeekNumber);  
   // Set year value  
   var new_yearcstField = attrParent.attributes.get("new_yearcst");  
   new_yearcstField.setValue(currentyear);  
 }  
 Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {  
   var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);  
   return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7);  
 }
```